# problems with facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated facebook sdk with my android app.

But users are facing a strange problem and I have searched a lot without any success in finding the solution.

The problem is, when user login for the first time, everything works fine. But when user log out and then login again, nothing happens. Just that white login screen appear and disapper in couple of seconds.

Any idea whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here. The Facebook account of that user is already associated with the app and the user does not need to provide permission again. If you check, you will see there will be an active session after the log-in.

Comment: Then you should post soms code, otherwise we will not be able to identify the problem